# How to change username used by github pull requests

Tags: git, github

I am seeing different usernames when pushing changes from bash vs. using a pull request in github.

In my .gitconfig file I set name = first last.  Which matches what I have in github.com under Public profile Name.  When I push changes from bash this is the name that gets used.

When I merge a pull request on github.com the username is getting used.  when I do a git log this causes these to show as different people under Author.

Right now it seems like the only way to work around this would be to ask everyone to change their config files to match this bad behavior, does anyone know of a better solution?

Comment: What is the `user.email` set to in your `.gitconfig` ? You might have to add all the email addresses you use to your `github` account under [Email Settings](https://github.com/settings/emails). The email addresses you add need not even be valid email addresses and you need not verify them, but helps you link all the different users/emails as a single one linked to your github account. Also note that this change will take effect on github.com only for future commits as far as I know.

Comment: the user.email in the gitconfig is set to the same as it is in github.  the change is made by the same account, it is just using different names for what shows up under "Author" in git log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution in talking to someone.  The issue was that github will set the author name to username if it doesn't have a name set in the users profile.  After changing that things work great.